# UserDefaults.standard data got deleted (payU money)

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am integrating payU money in my iOS app. Everything is working fine except one thing. Whenever I am returning from the payU money page all my values that are stored in UserDefaults are removed. I am using this code.

```
func startPaymentFlow() -> Void {
    UserDefaults.standard.set( "test" , forKey: "test")

    Toast(text:"Please wait.... Generating hash from server").show()
    let paymentVC : PUMMainVController = PUMMainVController()
    var paymentNavController : UINavigationController;
    paymentNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: paymentVC)

    self.present(paymentNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)    
}

func transactionCompleted(withResponse response : NSDictionary,errorDescription error:NSError) -> Void {

    self.dismiss(animated: true){
        self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Message", message: "congrats! Payment is Successful")
        self.Status = "1"
        self.MobilePaymentUpdateApi()
    }

}

func transactinFailed(withResponse response : NSDictionary,errorDescription error:NSError) -> Void {    
    self.dismiss(animated: true){
        self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Message", message: "Oops!!! Payment Failed")
        self.Status = "-1"
        self.MobilePaymentUpdateApi()
    }
}

func transactinCanceledByUser() -> Void {

    print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "test") as! String)

    self.dismiss(animated: true){    
        self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Message", message: "Payment Cancelled ")
        self.Status = "-1"
        print(self.Status)
        self.MobilePaymentUpdateApi()
    }
}
```

[image: This is error log and code]

getting this just after execution of

```
  self.present(paymentNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

Comment: is it possible that `transactinCanceledByUser` is called before `startPaymentFlow`?

Comment: no it is called after startPaymentFlow

Comment: Do you Store a value into that user defaults key anywhere else?  Have you set a breakpoint to confirm that `startPaymentFlow` is being called?

Comment: yes it is being called . and the user defaults that is show in code is for demo only . Real problem is that all  my device token id and other info which are stored in userDefaults are all cleared

Comment: [NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL  getting this after present statement